# To hit Pk table how can we get data related his fk key table

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have table user and login

Login: id(Pk), email, password

user has id(PK) login_id(FK), name

I have create a model

```
class Login(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True) 


class User(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    login = models.ForeignKey(Login)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, blank = True)
```

Now i create  serializers.py

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Login
        fields = ('id','email','password')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = LoginSerializer(source='login')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'login', 'name','data')
```

When i hit user  table then i get data from login table also

But when i hit Login table then i didn't get data from user table. how can i get data from user also if i hit any query on Login model

Comment: According to your models one login can be connected to several users. Are you sure that they are right?

Comment: As @zymud said, on login for many users looks weird, maybe you need a oneToOne relation, or using FK(User) on login to have multiple logins for one user.
To show what you ask, you will have to build two new serializers.

Comment: use prefetch_related https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related